# GCC Inline assembler access arguments?

Tags: gcc, gnu-assembler

I need to access an argument from a C function

void printk(char* msg);

and store it into ESI. However I can not do

```
mov $msg, %esi
```

or

```
mov $_msg, %esi
```

Both return a linker error (Saying that the symbol msg or _msg is undefined. I am pretty sure I could access msg by reading from the stack but it would be easier just to access the symbol msg in my assembly code. Is this even possible in GCC?

Comment: Can you show some more context?

Comment: I mean there is really nothing much to it. I am simply trying to use inline assembly to move the parameter message into ESI using

asm("mov $msg, %esi");

The compiler says that msg is undefined.

Comment: I don't think you can do that in gcc inline assembly.  Writing an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't refer to variables like that in GCC inline assembly.  I think you want something like:

```
 asm("mov %[msg], %%esi",
     : /* no outputs */
     : [msg] "r" (msg)
     : "esi");
```

Comment: Thanks that is what I needed, I come from a NASM background, so GAS is new to me.

Comment: Yeah, gcc-style inline assembly syntax might be terrible.  Maybe.

Comment: Depending on your ABI, you might find an "m" input constraint generates better code.

Comment: Even better would be `"rm"` allowing the compiler to use either a register or memory, whichever matches better with where the argument happens to be...

Comment: Cool - I didn't know that was allowed.  Good suggestion.

Comment: What do you mean by: `ask("mov %[msg], %%esi",` ?
What are you asking?

Comment: Should be `asm`. Fixed.